# How can I bundle installation profile with translation (*.po)

Tags: installation, distributions

I have tried a few different approaches to load a translation file (.po) from an installation profile.

The build is pretty close to being typical: a make file downloads core, custom profile  and application theme/modules. Then  `drush --site-install --profile cutstom_profile` build all of this

All is fine until I try adding locale in profile. Then everything breaks and depending on what I tried, different issues pop up that make it a show-stopper.

I tried having locale and l10n_update as dependencies and having a custom task set the language, but that triggers a database error when drush --site-install runs the second time with  saying it is trying to insert a duplicate.
I tried passing --locale=fr to site-install but that sets default french as default language / locale and is not what is wanted in this case. English is primary language.

Is there any way to install a language from a profile passed drush site-install?

- For those needing a fast and dirty way to deal with importing translation files on installation *without messing in a profile*, simply [install these locale oriented drush commands](http://drupal.org/project/drush_language) and automate the process with drush.